# System.QueryException: List has more than 1 row for assignment to SObject

Tags: apex, controller

I am trying to write a VF page to list all the id and name columns from a custom object but found an error "List has more than 1 row" in the VF page.  Can anyone tell me what have I done wrong?

**VF Page:**

```
<apex:page Controller="MP_controller" showHeader="false" sidebar="false">
  <apex:pageBlock>
     <apex:pageBlockTable value="{! mp}" var="item">
        <apex:column value="{! item.id}"/>
        <apex:column value="{! item.name}"/>

     </apex:pageBlockTable>
  </apex:pageBlock>
</apex:page>
```

**Apex controller**

```
global with sharing class MP_controller {
    public Merchant_Profile__c mp{get;set;}
    public MP_controller(){
        mp = [SELECT 
                ID, name, Profile_account_name__c, Merchant_ID__c, Bank_Code__c, Country_Code__c,
                Currency_Code__c, Merchant_Level__c, Merchant_Type__c, MSO__c, Region__c,
                Retail_Products__c, Transaction_Mode__c, Created_Date__c, Date_Disabled__c, Date_Live__c,
                Merchant_Category_Code__c 
              FROM Merchant_Profile__c
              WHERE Profile_Account_Name__c = '001O000000bQFnyIAG'];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your query is returning more than one record, but the variable 'mp' is a single instance and not a List of Merchant_Profile__c.
If you change the code as following, it will work.

```
public **List<Merchant_Profile__c>** mp{get;set;}
```

Comment: So can we take `mp` into an array while querying?

Comment: What exactly do you mean @Mr.Orange? mp is now a list and list is an array.

Answer (score 2):

The `pageBlockTable`'s `value` attribute expected a collection of data:

> value: The collection of data displayed in the page block table.

In your case this is a single object. You have to change it to the list for example:

```
public List<Merchant_Profile__c> mp { get; set; }
```